# ifstream can't find file

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to open a text file in c++ with ifstream but it won't locate the file even though the file is in the same directory as the .cpp file:

```
  #include <fstream>

  std::ifstream textInput("words.txt");
  if (!textInput) {
      return false;
```

I've triple checked and the file definately exists and is named correctly. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong with ifstream or with the path.

EDIT: I put the file in the current working directory of visual studio, it shows the files relative path as "words.txt", but it still can't find the file.

Comment: It's  a path problem - if you are running from an IDE, the file needs to be in your project directory.

Comment: Is it a Unicode program?  Does it work if you put in the full, absolute path?

Comment: I don't think you want the working directory of visual studio.  You want the working directory of your running program.

Answer (score 1):

Find out where you application is running (what is know as the "current working directory") using:

```
TCHAR NPath[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, NPath);
std::cout << NPath << std::endl;
```

Or if you are using C++17, you can do it using the standard library:

```
std::cout << std::filesystem::current_path().string() << std::endl;
```

Make sure that the file is located in the same path as the above snippets print.

Comment: Why not show how to do this cross-platform using [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/current_path)?

Comment: If anything, [this is the correct link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path). This is c++17, the chances his compiler supports that are --> 0... But I will improve my answer for the sake of future visitors :)

Comment: Thanks! I put the file in the path that spits out but it still won;t find the file :(. visual studio even shows it's relative path as "words.txt"

Comment: As an experiment -- if you put in the absolute path (for example it is likely to look like  "C:\somedirectory\words.txt" (Windows) or "/home/myname/somedirectory/words.txt" (Linux) ), does it find the file?

Comment: putting in the absolute path won't find the file either

Comment: @DanielTrugman I'd say the chances that one's compile supports `std::filesystem` are not too bad - MSVC has it under experimental namespace, GCC has it under an experimental header and namespace (also need to pass an additional linker option). Clang's support is being worked on, AFAIK. Additionally, in the future try avoiding "EDIT" sections for answers, as edit history is visible to everyone. Instead re-work/re-organize your answer to accomodate the clarifications/additions nicely, so it's easier to read for future visitors.