# unable to open file in visual studio

Tags: c++, io, fstream, iomanip

im learning c++ using visual studio as ide. I'm currently doing io streams, but when i try to open a file, the program doesn't open the file.

here is the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;

    file.open("Text.txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "open" << std::endl;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "not open" << std::endl;
 
}
```

i get the output as `not open`.

any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: All file paths that aren't absolute (starts with a slash) are relative. And they are relative to the running programs current [*working directory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). And when you run your program from an IDE the working directory is most likely not what you think it is. You can change the run settings to explicitly set the working directory, or change your program to use an absolute path to the file.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no canonical answer for this: [ifstream can't find file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46512383/ifstream-cant-find-file)

Comment: This might be the better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57281750/cant-open-txt-files-in-c-program-with-visual-studio-2019

Comment: @Botje If you have the time, then perhaps you could coalesce different sources and write that canonical answer? :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the answer i accepted worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to keep the file in the directory where the executable is generated by default when using Visual Studio.  this is typically located in your solution directory under a folder called Debug/Release depending on your configuration. check the project settings to see where the executable will be generated and copy the file there.

Comment: hey, updated the `open` line to this - `std::ifstream file{ "C:\Users\Kakshipth\Documents\VS\hola\Debug\test.txt" };`, which is the absolute path and this is were my `.exe` file is but im still getting the same output

Comment: For Visual Studio the default working directory is the project root directory IIRC, not the location of the executable.

Comment: @default-303 Remember that back-slashes are special inside strings, and needs to be escaped by a back-slash.

Comment: @so should i make a `.txt` file in `C:\Users\Kakshipth\Documents\VS\hola` since `hola` is the name of my project

Comment: Here's a tip. The answer above is correct for visual studio, but if you are confused about where the file needs to be, try making the same program but instead **write** a file not read it. Then look on your computer and see where that file has appeared. That's the same place you need to put the file for reading.

Comment: this answer is wrong! it depends on the current directory : i.e. from where the program was started or where program has set the current directory to.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem opening the csv file from cpp file and I found a solution by placing my csv file in the same folder where my source files and especially the cpp file(from which I am trying to open it) is placed.

Answer (score -2):

1)Make sure the path you given is correct.

2)Make sure the file you trying to open is already using by other processes.

3. Make sure the file exists the path given and and try by giving the full path of the file , if it works ,then make your adjustments.
4. Try to open the file manually and check if their is any problem with the file.
5. Check your file is protected by read-only or something like that.
6. Try to work with the below sample code, and reply me what error you are getting.

[file reading sample](https://svsivan.blogspot.com/2017/07/text-file-reading-c.html)

[file writing sample](https://svsivan.blogspot.com/2017/07/text-file-writing-c.html)

Comment: i tried the `file reading sample` and was getting this error = `Cannot open include file: 'stdafx.h': No such file or directory`

Comment: if you get the error stdafx.h' No such file or directory, then this the problem with visual studio installation may be. Try to repair your visual studio and then try

Comment: If you want to provide source code then add it to the answer directly, and don't use external links. The answer has to include all the necessary information to answer the question without the need to follow the link.